# Electric field near a uniformly charged ring using gauss law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Consider a uniformly charged ring having

$$\frac{Q}{L} = \lambda$$

Now consider a pipe of radius $r$ surrounding the ring. Now I want to find out the field on a point on this pipe. Considering this pipe to be Gaussian surface. Using Gauss' Law we have

$$\frac{Q_{in}}{\epsilon_0} = \int \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}$$

Now considering the field over this pipe like Gaussian surface to be uniform (?) we have

$$\frac{Q_{in}}{\epsilon_0} =  \vec{E} \int d\vec{s}$$

$$  \vec{E} =\frac{Q_{in}}{\epsilon_0 \cdot \Delta {S}} $$

now substituting $\Delta S = 4 \pi^2 R_{ring} \cdot r_{pipe}$

$$  \vec{E} =\frac{Q_{in}}{\epsilon_0 \cdot 4 \pi^2 R_{ring} \cdot r_{pipe}} $$

Now coming to my question(s) regarding this answer:

- Is this derivation and the answer correct
- If it is not where does this go wrong

What I have in mind is something along the lines of the following picture. Where I intend to calculate the field on the periphery of the blue torus which contains inside it a charged ring not a point on the axis.

[image of a torus which contains the uniformly charged ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Torus.svg)

Comment: The electric field lines are not symmetrical. You can't be sure if the electric field lines leave the gaussian surface normally i.e, $\vec{E}. \vec{dA} \neq E.dA$ (which they do not.)

Comment: @BhavyaSharma. How ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Electric field at a point on axis of uniformly charged ring using Gauss law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337889/)

Comment: @BhavyaSharma. I am asking about field on a torus which surrounds the ring and not a point on the axis of the ring.

Comment: I know the area. I have used it in the question for calculating the final answer. or possibly check out this link: (https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/torus.html) [Surface Area of Torus]

Comment: Alright, have you thought about the different values of electric field that you will get due to the superposition of electric field due to every charge on the ring ? The electric field in not uniform is the space surrounding the ring.

Comment: You have highlighted the weakness of your argument: the field over the pipe is NOT uniform hence $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec s\ne \vert\vec E\vert \cdot \oint ds$